# How can I add a resizing by scale layer to a model in tensorflow or keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, interpolation, resize-image

How can I add a resizing by scale layer to a model using tensorflow or keras ? ( not by fixed output dimensions)
for example i want to resize image shape (100, 100, 3) by up scale of 2 , so the output shape of that layer will be (200, 200, 3)
resizing layer should use interpolation methods like ( "bilinear", "nearest", "bicubic", "area")
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can't really be dynamic about image shapes within a dataset. To generate high speed execution on GPU, your images need to be fixed size.

That said, if all your images are a certain size within a dataset, but you want your model to generalize to different datasets, each with a different image size, you can just use an upsampling layer.

If you really need dynamic images within a dataset, and you know the largest image, you could center-pad all images until they match the correct size.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/UpSampling2D.

Comment: thank you , i m looking for a layer like tf.image.resize but the output should be resized by scale not by fixed height and weight (layer would be used in upscaling and downscaling )
because i want to be able to use the model with differents images size to predict.
i just read that UpSampling2D use just 2 interpolation nearest or bilinear , i want to use bicubic

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of such a layer... if non exists, you'd have to implement it yourself. If performance is not a problem, you can probably implement a custom layer and in the overridden call() method, you can drop into a @py_function that calls PIL/CV2. If performance is important, you'll want to do a pure tf impl. It'd be a pain... welcome to TF.

Comment: yeah thank you , can you give me a custom layer example with PIL.resize()

Comment: poke around stack overflow or see the tF guides - should be straightforward

Comment: You can totally use dynamic image sizes within the dataset, it's just a pain in the ass to setup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239474/tensorflow-variable-image-input-size-autoencoder-upscaling

Comment: You are correct Mahrkeenerh - the sizes can be dynamic within a dataset. but generally you get them all to the same size via cropping/padding before feeding to a model, because models train with batches and batches need all images the same size.